# How to open an explorer to select a directory with an SSH connection?

Tags: java, linux, unix, ssh

I have a Java program running on Windows. I need the user to select a directory in a Unix machine, not in the local machine.

I have an SSH connection to this Unix machine and thanks to a BufferedReader I can get the results of some commands like "pwd". Here is the code :

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import sshtest.Exec.MyUserInfo;
import java.io.*;

public class SSHConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            String user = "myUserId";
            String host = "unixmachines.company.corp";
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

            UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo();
            session.setUserInfo(ui);
            session.connect();

            String command = "pwd";

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

            ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);         
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

            channel.connect();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line;
            int index = 0;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(++index + " : " + line);
            }

            byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
            while(true){
                while(in.available()>0){
                    int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if(i<0)break;
                    System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                }
                if(channel.isClosed()){
                    if(in.available()>0) continue;
                    System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
                    break;
                }
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch(Exception ee){}
            }
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
              System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Now, I use this code to open an explorer to select a directory in the local machine (Windows) when clicking on a JButton :

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File(""));
chooser.setDialogTitle("choosertitle");
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): " + chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
        selectLabel.setText(chooser.getSelectedFile().toString());
        System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : " + chooser.getSelectedFile());
} else {
        System.out.println("No Selection ");
}
```

Since then, I think that I have to modify the second line of the last code replacing "java.io.File("")" by the path to the Unix machine thanks to the SSH connection.

So, once I get a path with the SSH connection (with the "pwd" command for instance), how can I adapt my second code to open an explorer on the Unix machine and not on the local machine ?

Thank you for your time and do not hesitate to ask me if I didn't give enough information.

Answer (score 1):

This creates a temporary directory, copies the file structure of my ~/Documents folder in the temp directory, and then displays the file chooser in the temp dir. This is really rough, but it should do what you asked about if you run the `find` command over SSH.

If you want a more robust solution, consider creating a `FileSystem` using your own implementation or using a tool like those contained in Guava.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CustomFileChooser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Function<String, Integer> countDir = str -> (str.length() - str.replace("/", "").length());

        List<String> directories = runCommand("cd ~/Documents && find . -type d ")
                .stream()
                .map(str -> str.substring(1))
                .sorted((o1, o2) -> {
                    Integer o1Count = countDir.apply(o1);
                    Integer o2count = countDir.apply(o2);
                    if (o1Count > o2count) return 1;
                    else if (o2count > o1Count) return -1;
                    else return 0;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        String url = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/javaFileChooser";
        File file = new File(url);
        Path p = Files.createDirectory(file.toPath());

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> runCommand("rm -rf " + file.toPath())));

        FileSystemProvider.installedProviders().get(0).checkAccess(file.toPath(), AccessMode.WRITE);

        directories.forEach(str -> {
            try {
                Files.createDirectory(new File(file.toPath().toString() + "/" + str).toPath());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setCurrentDirectory(file);
        fc.setSize(400, 400);
        fc.setVisible(true);
        fc.setControlButtonsAreShown(true);
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

    }

    public static List<String> runCommand(String command) {
        try (InputStream inputStream = Runtime.getRuntime()
                .exec(new String[]{"sh", "-c", command}).getInputStream();
             Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream)) {

            return new BufferedReader(in).lines().collect(Collectors.toList());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a gist I made: https://gist.github.com/prestongarno/b0034ae37ca5e757a35f996b4c72620d